# Is there an Android service or app that is similar to the IOS significant-change location service?

Tags: android, gps, location

The IOS significant-change location service would work nicely for my app to monitor location changes while preserving battery life.

Is there a similar service for Android or is there a third party app available?

Comment: This should go on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Agreed, this is not a development related question

Comment: @Aviral I agree with Femi. Looking for ways (either a service or a third party app) to improve your own app is development.

Comment: Yes, this clearly is a dev question. Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Criteria` class to specify your requirements.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
...
String bestProvider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Reference for `Criteria` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a third-party service, but you can use the Locator Manager's [RequestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) functionality to specify the period/magnitude of location change you want.

I'd say its a development-related question.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS documentation

> This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.

I think this stackoverflow post answers this better

[Best Practice to report user location continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332819/best-practice-to-report-user-location-continuously)

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that android used to let you do whatever you wanted: write a service, have it get the User's location continuously until the battery died. Starting with around N, that all went away. Now with O and P, they tell you point blank in their guidelines for what you can expect when being in the background:

> Background Location Limits
>
> In an effort to reduce power consumption, Android 8.0 (API level 26) limits how frequently background apps can retrieve the user’s current location. Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour.

So the answer is no. In iOS, you can still monitor the User's location from the background and the whole point of the Significant Change service is to allow you to do so efficiently.