# How to make an application run continuously in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an application which sends the location information to the server. But when the back or home button is clicked the application is stopped. Is there a way to make the application run continuously in background and sends data to the server ?

Comment: and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332819/best-practice-to-report-user-location-continuously

Comment: check commens ware location poler its the best out there for poling the location to a server  https://github.com/athulh/cwac-locpoll

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a background [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Services are application components which can run in the background without user interaction. A good tutorial on `Service` in android is from [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

You probably want to start the service on launch of your `Activity`, or you can register for system broadcasts like `BOOT_COMPLETE` to keep your service running from boot up.

However, keeping your service running throughout without user knowledge is a bad idea, and drains battery also. You probably want to wake up the service using `AlarmManager`, do processing, schedule next restart, and exit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a Service class for your own application.

Refer [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more information.