# Run Android services even Application closed

Tags: android, service

I have created the service  and its working fine while application is running. Service will stop when application instance closed. 
I **resolved this issue by calling service from GCM** notification appears and its not stop until the service operation complete.

But, Its **not working locally even I am sending the local notification**, Please anybody help to run the service in background even application closed .

Comment: What do you mean by "sending the local notification"?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is unclear as to what you are trying to achieve. Plus posting code where you think your error is will also help a lot.

Comment: When I calling service when GCM notification appear, its working and not stop even app closed. When I send the local notification then service stop when application closed

Answer (score 0):

Try startForeground(int, Notification) and stopForeground(boolean removeNotification) method as given on this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Comment: Thanks, my Same code work in Kitkat but not working on marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your service as `START_STICKY`. There is tons of information out there about this on Google for you to use. 
Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Dude, I had implement START_STICKY but its not working when application closed.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470967/how-to-make-an-application-run-continuously-in-android